# Bottle of wine bad bottom reflection

Tags: cycles-render-engine, transparency

i'm trying to create a bottle of wine. I'm totally new to 3d design and family, in fact i'm a web developer but i do like to learn and try new things! Now i struggling (a lot) on this project.

As you can see i have that bad color change (or reflection) and the bottom, which i dont know where coming from, i want to remove it! I tried a lot a different stuff like changing glossy and other proprieties...so i'm here because i need your help :)

Thanks, much appreciated!

Here some shots:

[image]

[**:: Download .blend**](https://expirebox.com/download/bb6fa1e613f25cb36562d9ca8a03ec14.html)

Comment: Do you have any idea or suggestion?

Comment: The shape of the wine doesn't follow the shape of the bottle. They intersect, and some parts of the wine are outside the bottle, while some parts are inside. http://i.imgur.com/AHmxz78.png

Comment: Yes, thats right! Thanks a lot :) That's becouse i dasabled the modifiers preview

Answer (score -1):

As Duane stated the problem was with the wine part that were placed outside the bottle. The problem wasn't visible becouse i had disabled the modfier preview during editing. Not it works just fine! Thanks